# how to properly validate a json based on a openapi schema?

Tags: c#, json, openapi

I'm trying to find a way to validate a json based on a yaml / json schema, following latest openapi specifications. Something like what we can do with xsd / xml.

input: json, schema
output: validation result

I have looked at nswag and newtonsoft and microsoft openapi implementation and so far I didnt find or get what I was expecting. Or the lack my google skill / documentation made me miss the way of doing it.

Comment: one problem with newtonsoft is that it is now limited / paid version

Comment: Do you have an example where you need it? I would have thought that a model class with proper attributation would be sufficient aka deserializing into such a class would fail therefore the json is not valid and you get a validation result in this case why deseserialization failed.